# Need to realign the colspec table item

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to realign the below output of the table colspec under the cols element

Input I'm having:

```
<table>
    <tgroup>
        <colspec colwidth="100pt"/>
        <colspec colwidth="100pt"/>
        <thead>
            <row>
                <entry>Claims</entry>
                <entry>Claims</entry>
            </row>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <row>
                <entry>Claims</entry>
                <entry>Claims</entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

XSLT I'm trying is the `copy-of` element:

```
<xsl:template match="table">
    <table>
      <cols>
        <xsl:copy-of select="colspec"/>
      </cols>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="tgroup">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="colspec">
    <col><xsl:attribute name="colwidth"><xsl:value-of select="@colwidth"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </col>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="thead">
    <thead>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </thead>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="tbody">
    <tbody>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tbody>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="row">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <td>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

Expected Output would be:

```
<table>
    <cols>
        <col colwidth="100pt"/>
        <col colwidth="100pt"/>
    </cols>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Claims</td>
            <td>Claims</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Claims</td>
            <td>Claims</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need the `colspec` elements needs to comes under the `cols` element. I have tried the `copy-of` method. But I can't able to fetch the elements under the `cols`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/table">
    <xsl:copy>
        <cols>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tgroup/colspec"/>
        </cols>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tgroup/(thead | tbody)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="colspec">
    <col colwidth="{@colwidth}"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="thead | tbody">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  
<xsl:template match="row">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
    <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```